# secret_key_base in Rails 6.0 best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, configuration

In Previous rails versions, the secrets file wasn't encrypted. So the best practice was to read, e.g. `secret_key_base`, from the environment.

This makes sense and it was pretty simple:

```
# config/secrets.yml

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

The Secrets served then as a simple logical directory for the keys.

in Rails 6.0 the file is encrypted and is not parsed, which means it must contain hard coded strings, i.e. the real secrets.

Is the best practice to have the value hardcoded and use the same key for all environments? This doesn't seem right.

Comment: The key reason that its not parsed is that you're not supposed to use ENV vars in it. While ENV vars are in many ways more secure then storing your credentials in a plaintext file they also are very vulnerable in that any gem can leak the entire ENV hash through sloppy debugging.

Comment: @max but you'll still have to put the secret in the env, right? So this is pretty much the same.

Comment: Not quite. If a gem leaks ENV they only get the encryption key. The attacker would still need to gain file system access to read the actual credentials. I guess thats kind of a moot point though if you code is in a public repo.

Comment: The key can also be supplied via a file.

Comment: @max yes, but having the key together with the encrypted file is kind of pointless...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When secure credentials where introduced in 5.2 you only had a single credentials file.

By popular demand Rails 6 will load a seperate `config/credentials/*.yml.enc` file - where `*` is the name of the environment if the file is present. This file takes complete precedence over `config/credentials.yml.enc` - the two are not merged.

You can edit the credentials for a specific environment by passing the environment option:

```
rails credentials:edit --environment development
```

See:

- [Rails PR #335219](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33521)

Comment: Is this the best practice? We have different  stages and settings, where all of them are configured the same (production env). Only some keys are different. If relying on this concept, we will have to have different environments just to store a different API key (thus duplicating production.rb, demo.rb, etc.). I think out problem, is that we misused `secrets` to organize the configuration, though this is not required. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is really just whats built into rails, DHH in particular wanted to keep it as simple as possible and backwards compatible while extending it for more advanced use cases is "left as a developer exercise". If this is really the "best practice way" of doing it is a matter of opinion.